# Update method behaving different according to Entity array size.

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, entity

I am making a college project and I am having trouble with my EntiyManager update method. This update system for some reason is making my bullets move faster according to my entity array size, if this array size is bigger than 1 the bullet will move faster if not the bullet will move normally.

I would like to have all my bullets moving normally.

note: b.getVel() and vel are always 2.

EntityManager methods:

```
public void update()
{
    if(!handler.getPaused())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < creatures.size(); i++)
        {
            //entities[i]       at
            Creatures c = creatures.get(i);
            c.update();

            if(!bullets.isEmpty())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bullets.size(); j++) 
                {
                    Bullet b = bullets.get(j);
                    //Hit detection;
                    if(c.getCollisionBounds(b.getVel(), 0).intersects(b.getCollisionBounds(0, 0)))
                    {
                        c.HP -= 5;
                        removeBullet(b);
                    }
                    System.out.println(b.getVel());
                    b.update();
                }
            } 
            else System.out.println("empty");
        }

    }

}



public void draw(Graphics g)
{

    for(Entity se : staticEntities)
    {
        se.draw(g);
    }

    for(Bullet b : bullets)
    {
        b.draw(g);
    }

    for(Creatures c : creatures)
    {
        c.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Bullet methods:

```
@Override
public void update() 
{
    if(vel > 0)
    { 
       txRight = (int) (x + vel + bounds.x + bounds.width) / Tile.TILESIZE;
    }  
    else
    {
       txLeft = (int) (x + vel + bounds.x) / Tile.TILESIZE; 
    }

    if(collisionWithTile(txRight, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILESIZE) ||
       collisionWithTile(txRight, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILESIZE) ||
       collisionWithTile(txLeft, (int) (y + bounds.y) / Tile.TILESIZE)  ||
       collisionWithTile(txLeft, (int) (y + bounds.y + bounds.height) / Tile.TILESIZE))
    {
        handler.getLevel().getEntityManager().removeBullet(this);
    }   

    x += vel;           
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) 
{   
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, width, height);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now know why this is happening. It is updating twice the bullet.